# Consuming webservice in MVC from controller or model?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

I need to call a webservice from my MVC5 project to populate a model. But I'm not sure if the call to the webservice should be made from the controller or from the model. Reading answers on Stackoverflow regarding this issue, seems to point in both directions. So where is the right place to put the call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit shocked nobody has answered this after 20 hours. Umm lets see here :) At minimum the controller would be responsible for this. Don't dirty up your model with responsibilities it shouldn't have.

I would create a service layer to handle this, the service layer would hold the refrence instead of the UI / web project, and then call _myservice.ExecuteSomeWebserviceMethod(); This really is just a light wrapper around the web service call but allows you more freedom to do things before returning whatever value(s) back to the controller.

You can inject the service into the constructor of the controller, it would be testable as well.